# How to send parameters on an Https POST with C#

Tags: c#, json, parameters, https, http-post

I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439678/https-post-from-php-to-c) how to make the https post, and now that works fine. Problem now is How to send a parameter, name query, which is a JSON string:

{"key1":"value1", "key2":{"key21":"val21"} }

What I'm doing and doesn't work is:

```
HttpWebRequest q = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Host + ":" + Port);
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
q.Method = "POST";
q.ContentType = "application/json";
q.Headers.Add("JSON-Signature", GetFirma(query));
q.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user,pass);

byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("query=" + query);

q.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

using (Stream stream = q.GetRequestStream())
{
     stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);                    
}
```

But the server always answer saying there's no 'query' parameter. Any help?

Comment: Doesn't the server maybe expect a query parameter in the URL? such as http://host/?query=xyz

Comment: That's what I don't know, as the only example supplied by server developers was on php (code in the first question)

Comment: See also: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/10/pass-data-simply-learning-from-jquery.html

Comment: Thanks Marc, it will be great to use MVC, or even .net 3.5. But i'm forced to use 2.0. But maybe i can try jquery aproach... Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `WebClient.UploadValues`:

```
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            NameValueCollection fields = new NameValueCollection();
            fields.Add("query", query);
            byte[] respBytes = client.UploadValues(url, fields);
            string resp = client.Encoding.GetString(respBytes);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I'm just getting the same answer as with my code. I'll try asking server developers again for more feed back.

Comment: Well, I have tried it locally and works great, so must be some compatibility issues or something similar.

Comment: Wouldn't this code post the request twice? You are calling client.UploadValues(url, fields); twice.